# Xamrain App Permission access denied issue?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, android-studio

i created an app in **Xamrain** my app is working fine till android API Level 28 but its not working in API Level 29 android 10 when i try to select a file from sdcard or internal memory then app throw an error file access danied please someone help me about this?